Azure Function - Handle Timeout Gracefully
I have two Azure Functions (separate Function Apps):

TimerFunctionOne - this is a potentially long running process fired up once per hour.
TimerFunctionTwo - short lived process, runs every 60 seconds.

My goal is to prevent TimerFunctionTwo from running if TimerFunctionOne is still executing.
Currently, I have TimerFunctionOne log to a database to flag when it starts and stops. TimerFunctionTwo can check this flag to determine if it can run or not.
The issue: if TimerFunctionOne falls over due to a timeout, it doesn't have an opportunity to affect the flag in the database and thus TimerFunctionTwo becomes blocked as it thinks TimerFunctionOne is still running.
I am thinking the best I can do is to have TimerFunctionOne periodically update the flag (timestamp) during its execution. TimerFunctionTwo can then infer the status of TimerFunctionOne based on when the flag was last updated.
I am curious if there is a better/more precise way to achieve my goal.

please share your both functions code

which programming language are you using?

Could you also share some details, why the second functions is not allowed to run in parallel to the first one? And what do you mean by "TimerFunctionTwo can check this flag to determine if it can run or not": If the second function needs to access the database, the function literally already "runs". Or do you mean that just part of your code within your function is not allowed to be executed?

If you switch to using Durable Functions instead, you could then use critical sections which are a type of shared lock. You could attempt to grab the lock in both FunctionOne and FunctionTwo, meaning that the first one would run while the second one waits til the lock ends. I can look to write an answer if you're interested. Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=function-based%2Cin-process%2Cpython-v2&pivots=csharp#example-transfer-funds
